# Ebook epub3 on Kindle Reader iOS iPhone is overriding CSS with ugly indented formatting?

Tags: epub, formatting, kindle-previewer

I have an epub I've hand coded that looks great in Kindle Previewer, iBooks, and Kindle Reader for iPad, and physical Kindles. However, on iPhone, it is gettting rid of the CSS formatting I've designed, including the custom font, and going with what looks like a very stripped down scrape of the content.

The main issue is that it is adding indentation to everything it sees as a paragraph. For instance, a list, which should look like this:

One
Two
Three

...ends up looking like this (dashes are to show spaces, not actually dashes):

--One
Two
Three

And every paragraph is indented too:

===

--Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

===

Alos, and this is something I've seen for years on other ebooks I've downloaded, that ordered lists have their first number bolded, the "1", like this:

**1.** This
2. That
3. Other
4. Thing

Does anyone know how to prevent this? Why does Kindle Previewer 3 on phone show me what I expect to see with my layout, custom font, etc, but then on Kindle iOS, I get this stripped down version. Again, iPad is perfect, no problems. Just on iPhone...